# Remove boxes from wordpress comments

Tags: php, wordpress

I hope someone can help me with this or point me in the right direction. I'm currently pulling my hair out.

On the wordpress comments form. I have these boxes:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwRE2.png)

I have looked at the wordpress functions page: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form which mentioned this **'comment_notes_before' => ''** - Even if I made the value blank it still adds those bloody boxes!!!!

Can someone please tell me how to remove them?

p.s I am using the standard **comment_form($comments_args);** implementation not a custom form.

Thanks

EDIT: Full Code

```
<?php
  $fields = array(

   // author field
   'author' => '',

   //email field
   'email' => '',

   'comment_notes_before' => '',
   'comment_notes_after' => ''

 );
?>

        <?php

        $comments_args = array(
  'id_form'           => 'commentform',
  'class_form'      => 'comment-form',
  'id_submit'         => 'submit',
  'class_submit'      => 'submit',
  'name_submit'       => 'submit',
  'title_reply'       => __( 'Leave a Reply' ),
  'title_reply_to'    => __( 'Leave a Reply to %s' ),
  'cancel_reply_link' => __( 'Cancel Reply' ),
  'label_submit'      => __( 'Post Comment' ),
  'format'            => 'xhtml',

  'comment_field' =>  '<p class="comment-form-comment"><label for="comment">Comment</label><textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true">' .
    '</textarea></p>',

  'must_log_in' => '<p class="must-log-in">' .
    sprintf(
      __( 'You must be <a href="%s">logged in</a> to post a comment.' ),
      wp_login_url( apply_filters( 'the_permalink', get_permalink() ) )
    ) . '</p>',

  'logged_in_as' => '<p class="logged-in-as">' .
    sprintf(
    __( 'Logged in as <a href="%1$s">%2$s</a>. <a href="%3$s" title="Log out of this account">Log out?</a>' ),
      admin_url( 'profile.php' ),
      $user_identity,
      wp_logout_url( apply_filters( 'the_permalink', get_permalink( ) ) )
    ) . '</p>',

  'fields' => apply_filters( 'comment_form_default_fields', $fields ),
);
?>
```

Comment: Does this help: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-remove-comment-box-from-a-page

Comment: Thank you for your reply but unfortunately it does not. I want the comments form to be visible I just don't want those little boxes above the comment textarea field

Comment: Those "boxes" are the indication of which tags a user can use.  Those can be suppressed by the `comment_notes_after` argument (not sure where you got the 'comment_notes_before').  Also, we'd need to see your full code, as well as the fact that your theme / plugins could be hijacking this.

Comment: added the full code. I have both the _before and _after set to ' ' already. :/

Comment: i had a quick look at the documentation, i can't see where you remove the buttons, if its the same set up as the text editors they are addd with js,  but you can use css and set them to `display: none` which would be a quick solution.

Comment: @david Thank you for that. I just got the class name of the div and did what you said. Do you want to add that as a proper answer so that I can give you the rep points?

Comment: @JamesG no problem, dont worry about the points its not really a proper answer, but you've said thank you which is enough :)

Comment: @david Manners only cost a second, and in a day there are 86,400 to spend

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS selectors to style the comments area is absolutely the best way given there are no WordPress hooks to control this.

> i had a quick look at the documentation, i can't see where you remove the buttons, if its the same set up as the text editors they are addd with js, but you can use css and set them to display: none which would be a quick solution. – [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2430392/david) Dec 16 '15 at 1:18

David has the right idea and it looks like that did the trick. Before scanning the comments I was on-top of it - CSS!!!

**I'm answering this question so it no longer shows as unanswered.**